# Problema com .htaccess, subdomínio

Tags: laravel, htaccess

Eu tenho no meu site (root) uma instalação laravel, ou seja, na pasta public_html eu tenho um ficheiro .htaccess com:

```
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    <FilesMatch "\.(html|php|txt|xml|js|css)$">
        SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
    </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Pelo pouco que percebo de htaccess, acho que isso está a fazer com que 'public' desapareça e seja substituido pelo quer que seja que venha a seguir. Até aqui tudo bem. O problema surge quando tenho uma outra app num subdominio deste domínio, não deve ser relevante mas esta não é laravel, é do mais simples html/css/js feito de raiz, aparece o erro 500, internal server error. Mas se eu retirar o .htaccess acima da root já deixa de acontecer, e aparece tudo bem, mas com o problema de para aceder ao site principal tenha de escrever site_principal.com/public/ (a minha instalação laravel).

Em baixo uma foto da estrutura de links.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2):

Na pasta raiz do Laravel, cria um arquivo .htaccess com esse código:

Acrescenta essas duas linhas no .htaccess da pasta **public_html**

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?claradvl\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?(index.\php)?$ /fitkick [L]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
```

Comment: E na pasta raiz do subdominio? tenho de fazer alguma coisa? Na pasta public do laravel já tenho isso, aliás até vem por default

Comment: Ela não precisa ter .htaccess se estou entendendo o que tu disse...

Comment: Exato também achava que não, mas dá erro 500

Comment: Edita a pergunta e coloca uma imagem do FTP ou 'desenha' a árvore de diretórios.

Comment: Editada a pergunta

Comment: Editei a resposta.

Comment: Desculpa, mas agora dá o erro nos dois, na root e no subdomínio. O meu htaccess só tem isso que me disse, essas 4 linhas